# Testing linear extrapolation for validity

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, extrapolation

How can we assess the validity of a linear extrapolation? Is there a standard way of measuring the soundness of an extrapolation, like "statistical significance"?

The only way I can think of is to take the ratio of the sample with the population. For instance, if `sample = 24` and `population = 200 billion`, their ratio is `0.00000000012` or `1.2e-10`. How do we know if this is a valid linear extrapolation? Here, 24 is the number of galaxies Edwin Hubble observed in 1929 and 200 billion is the accepted number of galaxies in the observable universe.

What I’m trying to understand is this:

If Hubble observed just one galaxy and extrapolated that to the entire universe, no one would have believed him. If we assume that there are 200 billion observable galaxies then the ratio, `sample/population` is `1/2e11 = 0.0000000000050` or `5.0e-12`.

If Hubble measured 2 galaxies, I believe, people would still question that extrapolation. Even instinctively, projecting a sample of 2 to 200 billion appears invalid.

If Hubble observed 10 galaxies, the ratio is `10/2e11 = 0.0000000000500` or `5.0e-11`. That’s one order of magnitude difference from 1 galaxy, right?

In reality, Hubble observed 24 galaxies and extrapolated that linearly to 200 billion galaxies and no one objected to it. The ratio for 24 galaxies is: `24/2e011 = 0.0000000001200` or `1.2e-10`. To me this is no different than observing only one galaxy and projecting it to 200 billion.

So, how do we determine that a linear extrapolation is valid? Is there a measure like “Statistical significance” for extrapolations?

For instance, [in this site](https://news.mit.edu/2012/explained-sigma-0209#:%7E:text=The%20unit%20of%20measurement%20usually,together%2C%20or%20very%20spread%20out) they write, regarding statistical significance, that,

> if you’re taking a poll on how people plan to vote in an election, the
> accepted convention is that two standard deviations above or below the
> average, which gives a 95 percent confidence level, is reasonable.
> That two-sigma interval is what pollsters mean when they state the “margin of
> sampling error,” such as 3 percent, in their findings.

How do I calculate 2 sigma for this case?

Please note that, I never studied statistics (sorry if my terminology is off) but I would like to know the mathematics involved here. Thanks.

Comment: In what sense is what you describe with those galaxies a *linear* extrapolation ? By "this case" you mean again the 24 galaxies ? How convincing Hubble's results are to physicists and astronomers is in my opinion neither a math question nor a very interesting statistics question. Please post on the relevant SE sites.

Comment: By linear extrapolation I refer to the equation of the line: "Two quantities y and x are linearly proportional to one another if they always obey an expression of the form: `y = k x where k is a constant.`". The physics or astronomy part is not important. I'm not talking about gravity or any physical theory. It's just an example. So can you explain, if this is not linear extrapolation what is it? It seems to me there is a sample and a population so statistic somehow must be involved. I'm only interested in the mathematical side.